# Powershell Newbie: How do I filter results so that only the information I get back can be used in a pipeline?

Tags: powershell, pipeline, group-policy

Lets say I run a powershell command (in my case Group Policy related) but lets say I run this command:

PS C:>Get-GPO -All

and my output looks like:

DisplayName   : My Named GPO

DomainName    : mydomain.com

Owner         : Domain Admins

Id            : Random_GUID
...

How can I "filter" that command so that it only returns the lines relating to DisplayName?  Is that possible or will I need to do some string parsing that's not available inside a pipeline operation?  Because ultimately, I'm looking to use that DisplayName param to pipe to another command.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Select-Object (or select in short)

```
Get-GPO -All | Select DisplayName
```

Comment: And if you need just string values as the result (not PS objects with a single property `DisplayName`) then use this: `Select-Object -ExpandProperty DisplayName`